# How can I implement a Blurred Background effect of Scaffold or the bottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, background

I am making an app project in Flutter, where I want a blurred background Bottom Navigation Bar. How can I implement a bottom navigation bar in scaffold with blurred background property?

[My code of Scaffold in Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLPeL.png)

Comment: You can use backdrop filter widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below one as widget and change background as image or color you wish and remove unwanted params as per you need.

```
class GlassBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final double blurRadius, cornerRadius, width, height;
  final Border outline;
  final BoxShadow shadow;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Widget child;

  const GlassBox({
    Key? key,
    this.width = 100,
    this.height = 100,
    this.blurRadius = 4.0,
    this.cornerRadius = 10,
    required this.child,
    required this.outline,
    required this.shadow,
    this.backgroundColor = const Color(0x44ffffff),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double blurSigma = blurRadius * 0.57735 + 0.5;
    final borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(cornerRadius);

    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          ClipPath(
            clipper: _InvRRectClipper(cornerRadius),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: borderRadius,
                boxShadow: [
                  if (shadow != null) shadow,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: borderRadius),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blurSigma, sigmaY: blurSigma),
              child: Container(color: const Color(0x0), child: child),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            foregroundDecoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: outline, borderRadius: borderRadius),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: backgroundColor,
              borderRadius: borderRadius,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _InvRRectClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double radius;

  _InvRRectClipper([this.radius = 12]);

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final p = Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBR(
        0,
        0,
        size.width,
        size.height,
        Radius.circular(radius),
      ))
      ..addRect(Rect.largest)
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
    return p;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```